# Using OpenCV to extract an exact region from a scanned paper?

Tags: python, opencv

We basically have designed a template on paper and need OpenCV to extract an exact region from a scanned A4 size sheet (Say a 5cmx5cm region at   the point (5cm,7cm) ).

Right now I've placed 4 objects (4 hexagons) at the 4 corners and used the template matching code (found [here](http://opencv-python-tutroals.readthedocs.org/en/latest/py_tutorials/py_imgproc/py_template_matching/py_template_matching.html)) to try to get the locations of all 4 hexagons and then use that as my guide to navigate the page. But the template matching code returns quite a few points (very close to each other).

So is this the right way to go about it? Is there (and should I use) any algorithms to find the "mean" of these points or is there a *better* method to go about this?

```
import cv2
import numpy as np
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt

img_rgb = cv2.imread('Template.jpg')
img_gray = cv2.cvtColor(img_rgb, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)
template = cv2.imread('hex.png',0)
w, h = template.shape[::-1]

res = cv2.matchTemplate(img_gray,template,cv2.TM_CCOEFF_NORMED)
threshold = 0.8
loc = np.where( res >= threshold)
for pt in zip(*loc[::-1]):
    cv2.circle(img_rgb, pt, 1, (0,0,255))

cv2.imwrite('res.png',img_rgb)
```

Here are the images: [image: Basic Template]
[image: Image to be found]

Results:
[image]

Comment: Can you add your code & results images?

Comment: @BalajiR Sorry, didn't think they'd be necessary since the code doesn't have much changes - updated the question.

Answer (score 1):

Ok you are applying threshold to the result image. 
i.e

```
res = cv2.matchTemplate(img_gray,template,cv2.TM_CCOEFF_NORMED)
threshold = 0.8
```

If you want to find the Max value using minMaxLoc & it is described in the tutorial page itself. More [info here](http://answers.opencv.org/question/54254/some-brainstorming-help-to-detect-speckles/#54260)

```
import cv2
import numpy as np
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt

img = cv2.imread('messi5.jpg',0)
img2 = img.copy()
template = cv2.imread('template.jpg',0)
w, h = template.shape[::-1]

# All the 6 methods for comparison in a list
methods = ['cv2.TM_CCOEFF', 'cv2.TM_CCOEFF_NORMED', 'cv2.TM_CCORR',
            'cv2.TM_CCORR_NORMED', 'cv2.TM_SQDIFF', 'cv2.TM_SQDIFF_NORMED']

for meth in methods:
    img = img2.copy()
    method = eval(meth)

    # Apply template Matching
    res = cv2.matchTemplate(img,template,method)
    min_val, max_val, min_loc, max_loc = cv2.minMaxLoc(res)

    # If the method is TM_SQDIFF or TM_SQDIFF_NORMED, take minimum
    if method in [cv2.TM_SQDIFF, cv2.TM_SQDIFF_NORMED]:
        top_left = min_loc
    else:
        top_left = max_loc
    bottom_right = (top_left[0] + w, top_left[1] + h)

    cv2.rectangle(img,top_left, bottom_right, 255, 2)

    plt.subplot(121),plt.imshow(res,cmap = 'gray')
    plt.title('Matching Result'), plt.xticks([]), plt.yticks([])
    plt.subplot(122),plt.imshow(img,cmap = 'gray')
    plt.title('Detected Point'), plt.xticks([]), plt.yticks([])
    plt.suptitle(meth)

    plt.show()
```

Comment: Yes, but I need a specific coordinate so that I can navigate the page

Comment: minMaxLoc unfortunately only returns the single most matching point, I would like to know the location of all 4 otherwise I wouldn't know which point the program is referring to.

Comment: Please see this link & adapt the c++ code for python http://answers.opencv.org/question/54254/some-brainstorming-help-to-detect-speckles/#54260